# How to aggregate duplicate rows based on complex set of column conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm using pandas to explore a data set with multiple duplicate entries. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'ID':['001','001','002','002','002','003','003','004','004'],
             'a':['Yes','Yes','Yes','No','Yes','Yes','No','No','No'],
             'b':['NaN',3,'NaN',5,4,7,'NaN','NaN','NaN']})

ID  a   b
001 Yes NaN
001 Yes 3
002 Yes NaN
002 No  5
002 Yes 4
003 Yes 7
003 No  NaN
004 No  NaN
004 No  NaN
```

Each duplicate `ID` should be combined into a single row in which the values of the columns are aggregated according to the following rules:

- if present in the column, `Yes` should supersede `No`
- if present in the column, a number should replace `NaN` and if more than one number are present the largest number should be chosen.

The expected result is:

```
ID  a   b
001 Yes 3
002 Yes 5
003 Yes 7
004 No  NaN
```

I have tried (and failed) to create a custom function then to use apply and lambda. However, I don't think that is the right approach as I can't see a way for these row-wise operations to work on a group of duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `max` after replacing `'NaN'` strings with `np.nan`. This works specifically because `'Yes' > 'No'` returns `True`. For greater efficiency, I advise you convert series `a` into either a Categorical or Boolean series.

```
# replace 'NaN' strings with np.nan
df['b'] = df['b'].replace('NaN', np.nan)

# groupby + max, reset index to elevate index to column
res = df.groupby('ID').max().reset_index()

print(res)

    ID    a    b
0  001  Yes  3.0
1  002  Yes  5.0
2  003  Yes  7.0
3  004   No  NaN
```